# How can I responsively scale a single image file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

I have the following `img` tag, which sits inside a container with 30 pixels of horizontal padding. It is therefore designed to show a 640-pixel wide image if the screen is >=670 pixels wide, and otherwise a 320-pixel wide image:

```
<img srcset="TestImage320.png 320w, TestImage640.png 640w"
     sizes="(max-width: 669px) 320px, 640px"
     src="TestImage320.png">
```

However, the 640-pixel image is simply a manually scaled-up version of the 320-pixel image. Is it possible to achieve the same effect without creating (and requiring users to download) the 640-pixel image?

Essentially, my current approach chooses between `src="TestImage320.png"` and `src="TestImage640.png"` values depending on the available width. Instead, I want to keep `src="TestImage320.png"` and choose between `style="width: 320px"` and `style="width: 640px"`. How can I achieve this (or something equivalent)?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to scale up an image, it will look bad. You can scale down better and still keep some nice quality.

I would only include the 640px version. Throw a `max-width: 640px; width: 100%;` and watch it scale down perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are significantly worried about load time it is often best to use the largest image you need (in your case 640px) and then scale it down to 320px. Keep in mind with the prevalence of retina displays it is recommended that you double the resolution of your image so it still looks nice on those displays. But again it's a load time vs image quality question, though an image at 1280px shouldn't be a super huge file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this style on your image it will scale and keep integrity according to width.

```
.imageClass{  
width:100%
height:auto;
float:left;
}
```

If you need it to remain a certain height this will keep integrity according to height.

```
.imageClass{  
width:auto;
height:100%;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File HTML:

```
<div class="text-img">
    <img src="text.jpg" alt="text" title="text" />
</div>
```

File CSS:

```
.text-img {width:100%;max-width:640px;overflow:hidden;}
.text-img img {min-height:100%;}
```